# Best practice with storing images on server

Tags: php, image, storage, gd

people! Please suggest me what is the best practice to store and retrieve images with my php application. My app uses different sizes of uploaded images (thumb, small, middle, big e.t.c). My current script creates all of the sizes after success image upload and stores 5 different version of every image. As the result, I'm running out of hosting storage space very fast.

So I want to ask: maybe better way to store only one original file and generate smaller sizes on the fly with php when image retrieves (maybe using some sort of cache)? Or which is the best practice by your opinion?

Comment: this is also bad idea (generate on the fly). even worse than current one. you will face cpu overload very fast

Comment: @andre3wap store images bytes in DB will have the same effect - disk space will reduce. even worse, if you delete data from DB it's not actually deleted until you do vacuumize.

Comment: @heximal - yup - that's true. Bad Practice. Buy more hosting space =D

Comment: I would suggest using a service like Amazon S3 if storage space is a problem, what you are doing is the "best practice" by creating each sized element and storing them in the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store 1 max size version of the image on the server and then use something like TimThumb to resize on load.